# Sprites disappear after game is built (unity engine C#) Not an issue of layer they are on

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I am currently writing a 2D game in unity and whenever I build the actual game, the sprites all disappear, the player is the only thing that remains.

However, the sprites are still there, just invisible. It's not an issue of order of layer and am having trouble fixing it.

I am using `SpriteShapeController`.

Comment: Create a material for your sprites and set the shader as "Unlit -> Transparent".Then assign this material to all your sprite components. Build and Try it.

Comment: @saif Wasnt the problem but i just figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpriteShapeController` auto shows as it having a sprite so it made me think I had a sprite already
I just made Custom Square Sprites and added them in.